# spring data mongodb: E11000 duplicate key error collection replica set. Occurs even after checking whether data with unique key exists or not

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

The issue that I am facing is intermittent and occurs only in the production environment during heavy loads.
MongoDB is set up in replica set mode with an arbiter.

I have a UserDetail class

```
@Builder
@Data
@Document(collection = "user_details")
public class UserDetail {

    private List<String> params;

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Indexed(name = "idx_us_de_on_user_id", unique = true)
    private UUID userId;

}
```

In the service layer before saving, I first check whether it exists or not through the following code:

```
UserDetail userDetail =
                Optional.ofNullable(
                        mongoTemplateReadPreferencePrimary
                                .query(UserDetail.class)
                                .matching(
                                        query(where("userId").is(userId))
                                )
                                .firstValue()
                )
                .orElse(
                        UserDetail.builder()
                                .userId(userId)
                                .params(new ArrayList<>())
                                .build()
                );

// perform business logic

// then try to save userDetail
userDetailRepository.save(userDetail);
```

The repository layer is as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDetailRepository extends MongoRepository<UserDetail, ObjectId> {

    Optional<UserDetail> findByUserId(UUID userId);

}
```

But in production environment during heavy loads sometimes I get the error

```
Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: database_name.user_details index: userId_1 dup key: { userId: UUID("b5261508-fdc8-4f30-b358-5d37374cf9f9") }', details={}}
```

I tried using readConcern as primary but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have a race condition. Two concurrent requests to update the same `UserDetail` will find the entity does not exist and try to do an insert and one of them will throw a duplicate key error

Options:

- Implement `Persistable` with `isNew()` false so save is always an upsert
- Implement business logic so you always do two tries. The second try only if you get a duplicate key exception